# C++ Multiple inheritance casting from derived class to base class

Tags: c++

I have something like this:

```
class A;
class B;
class C: public A, public B;

auto c = make_unique<C>();
```

I have a method

```
void doExcitingStuff(unique_ptr<B> &b)
{}
```

I am struggling to find a way to cast C so I can pass C into this method.  Am I looking at it the wrong way or is this just not possible?  I feel I should be able to cast down like this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Damien

Comment: "to cast down like this" -- like what?  `B* b = &c;` would work, so the question is not how to cast from derived class to base class, because a cast is not even necessary; the question is how to assign an existing instance of `C` to that `unique_ptr<B> &b` that your exciting function accepts, and we do not know how you are trying to do that.

Comment: What is the problem you are actually trying to solve? (multiple) inheritance hardly ever is the solutio, unless you inherit from multiple abstract baseclasses (interfaces).

Comment: Converting to a base class is **up**casting not downcasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a cast here, since `std::unique_ptr<C>` and `std::unique_ptr<B>` are entirely unrelated types. You need to create a new `std::unique_ptr<B>` taking over the ownership from `c`.

```
class A
{
};

class B
{
public:
    virtual ~B() = default;
};

class C : public A, public B
{
};

void doExcitingStuff(std::unique_ptr<B>& b)
{}

int main()
{
    auto c = std::make_unique<C>();

    std::unique_ptr<B> b(std::move(c));

    doExcitingStuff(b);
}
```

If `c` isn't actually needed anywhere else in your program, you could also create `b` directly instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<B> b = std::make_unique<C>();
```

Note that unless `doExcitingStuff` actually modifies the unique pointer object itself (not referring to modifying the object pointed to here), you should be passing the object by reference or as a raw pointer depending on whether you're allowed to pass null or not:

```
void doExcitingStuff2(B&)
{}

void doExcitingStuff3(B*)
{}

...

doExcitingStuff2(*c);
doExcitingStuff3(c.get());
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to make method signatures with unique pointers.
Or to make an explicit instance of std::unique_ptr (like the other answer). Casting unique_ptr's is also a bit tricky because you would have to transfer owner to the new unique_ptr too.
I would do it like this :

```
#include <memory>

class a_itf
{
public:
    virtual void do_a() = 0;
};

class b_itf
{
public:
    virtual void do_b() = 0;
};

class class_c_t final:
    public a_itf,
    public b_itf
{
    void do_a() override {};
    void do_b() override {};
};

// naked pointers are non-owning pointer so you can still use them as argument types
// see https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning
// using a unique_ptr& is too strong a requirement and get you painted into a corner

void do_something_a(a_itf* a)
{
    if (a != nullptr)
    {
        a->do_a();
    }
}

void do_something_b(b_itf* b) 
{
    if (b != nullptr)
    {
        b->do_b();
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto c = std::make_unique<class_c_t>();
    do_something_a(c.get());
    do_something_b(c.get());
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you use shared_ptr instead of unique_ptr?

Then you can do this:

```
void doExcitingStuff(std::shared_ptr<B> b)
{

}

int main()
{
    auto c = std::make_shared<C>();
    doExcitingStuff(c);
}
```